# TextView animation

Tags: android, animation, textview

I find a good external lib to implement many beautiful Textview animations. The link is this: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
I have a problem to implement it. I have imported correctly all 3 libs and I use correctly the function like in the dev's example:

YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(700).playOn(findViewById(R.id.TextView1));

Eclipse doesn't segnalate me any problem. But when I launch the application, it crashes

p.s. sorry for my bad english, I'm italian :(

EDIT 1:

logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3675)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.Techniques
enter code here
```

Comment: Did you check `logcat`?

Comment: Please post more details about the crash

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My problem was missing dependency AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0. Please make sure all dependencies are included into the project correctly. See https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations.

Comment: I solved this problem with android studio, with eclipse I had too many problmes, with AS all work perfectly! Anyway thank you ;)